# To which file does the Camel log predicate write?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a `RouteBuilder` route that includes:

```
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Unknown type on reporting queue")
```

Sorry for this question, but there does this get logged? hawtio confirms it is being executed.  But it isn't in either of the `/var/log/tomcat/myproject.log` or `var/log/tomcat/myproject/camel.log` files.  I also didn't see it in `/var/log/messages`

I see messages logged from my beans in `myproject.log` but nothing logged by the `.log(...)` predicate.

**EDIT**
After a little digging I found that slf4j can sit on top of log4j. I found a config file and was able to write to the log I was expecting by inserting the appropriate identifier in the log predicate:

```
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "com.mycompany.mything", "Unknown type on reporting queue")
```

`com.mycompany.mything` is defined in the log4j file such that it writes to the desired log file.

That's not a very precise description, but frankly Java logging mystifies me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel uses slf4j: the log it not directly written to a file, but through a logger, which is globally configured to write it in files. This configuration is out of camel responsibility.

The strategy to find a logger is implemented on the [LogDefinition](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/LogDefinition.java#L87) class.

Basically :

1. A logger can be explicitly specified
2. A slf4j Logger is look up in the registry
3. A slf4j logger is created with a name which can be explicitly specified, and if not set, it fallback to the identifier of the route

So, if you didn't set a logger in your registry, and didn't set a routeId, then the logger should be something like "route-1". the log level is used to: your log will be in the debug level (by default, it's probably not printed)